# Behaviour of background-size: cover in combination with background-position

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup where I try to set `background-size: cover` and try out the different background positions with it. Also check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5ysc92k/) in action.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container {
  background: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iCnFX7eWVjs/XR9NQutHXcI/AAAAAAAAJ9k/ISWH3UXgJF8QJdsV6P9wh3agzOwOF_aYgCLcBGAs/s1600/cat-1285634_1920.png);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

**My question**
Why changing the Y-axis value for `background-position` doesn't have any effect (same with `top`, `center` and `bottom`? It always shows the same area of the image on the Y-axis. How can I predict what part of the image will be shown given a container's size and image's size?

**What I tried/learnt so far**
What I understood is that it strongly depends on aspect ratio of both the container and the image. Making the container 500x250 px makes the Y-axis now variable, but now the X-axis stays always the same when setting `left`, `center` or `right` for it. Asking the question in different Discord channels, I also got an answer that image fits only in one axis and overlaps in another (that is, one of them is always static regardless of value). Is that true? Are there situations where both X-axis and Y-axis are dynamic and change position when supplied with different values?

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76855015/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question

Comment: I think you have basically answered your question. With size cover the system will crop at only one of top/bottom or left/right.

Comment: @AHaworth, I guess that's correct. But I'm trying to understand how it chooses which axis to be dynamic and which not. Say we use [this image](http://placekitten.com/g/300/400) instead (3:4 aspect-ratio) on a 500x250 container (2:1 or 8:4 ratio), the Y-axis is dynamic and X not. Is there any explanation or formula for this?

Comment: If the y direction was fixed to the container height then the image would not cover the whole container widthwise, it fixes whichever dimension will leave at least enough in the other direction to cover the container.

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks a lot, but can you give an example with an image and a container and how these things work there? Didn't quite understand what *If the y direction was **fixed** to the container* and *it fixes whichever dimension will leave **at least enough in the other direction** to cover the container* mean.

Answer (score -1):

If `background-position` has a keyword value like `right` `left` `bottom` `center` or `top` the first value will simply override the other although [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) sort of state the opposite.

This can be bypassed by using units instead of keyword values like:
`background-position: 200px 200px`
`background-repeat: no-repeat`

adding `background-repeat: no-repeat` will also make it a single image which will allow you to see the effects of it.